# How to change from "file_get_contents" to "wp_remote_get"

Tags: plugins

I need to change my one of my plugin's function to use "wp_remote_get" instead of "file_get_contents" and I am having trouble with it even though I found similar threads that have this problem, I still am not able to get it to work with "wp_remote_get". With "file_get_contents", it works perfectly fine but with "wp_remote_get", it doesn't.

This is the code I'm trying to change

```
private static function geolocate_via_api( $ip_address ){
    $response = file_get_contents( "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip_address);
    return json_decode( $response, true );  
}
```

I have tried the code below but it showed an error "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" in line 42 which is also shown below.

Error:

```
foreach ( $data as $key => $value) {
        $mo_data[ str_replace( 'geoplugin_', '', $key ) ] = $value;
    }
```

Code I tried:

```
    private static function geolocate_via_api( $ip_address ){
    $response = wp_remote_get( esc_url_raw('http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=' . $ip_address) );     
    return json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );   
}
```

Would really appreciate any help I can get. Cheers.

Comment: Escaping functions are meant to be used on output, but here I see `esc_url_raw` being used on a parameter for `wp_remote_get`, can I ask why? This is very unusual. Keep in mind as well that geolocation is extremely unreliable and easy to spoof. As a UK user I spent 15 years recieving USA websites due to the ISP I used. It's also really annoying if I'm abroad on holiday or for business to find I can't use the UK site, or if i want to purchase or check something for a friend in another country

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no error checking on any of the code, both the `file_get_contents` code, and the `wp_remote_get` code. **Don't just assume it worked, *check*!**

```php
$response = file_get_contents( "http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=" . $ip_address);
if ( false === $response ) {
    // it failed, abort!
```

Three steps, first, make the request:

```php
$response = wp_remote_get( $url );
```

Note that we aren't using `esc_url_raw`, escaping is for enforcing assumptions on output, this is not browser output. If needed, use `urlencode` on the IP.

Then, we want to perform error checking. Your code performs no error checking of any kind, even in the `file_get_contents` example, it just assumes it worked. This is incorrect. Don't just assume functions work, check for error values.

So before we use the result:

```php
if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    // it's an error! Abort!
```

Here we can look at the error message in the response object to see what went wrong. Take a look at the `WP_Error` documentation for how to do that.

Then, look inside the `$response` to see what the result was. `$response` contains several items:

- 'headers' (string[]) Array of response headers keyed by their name.
- 'body' (string) Response body.
- 'response' (array) Data about the HTTP response.
- 'code' (int|false) HTTP response code.
- 'message' (string|false) HTTP response message.
- 'cookies' (WP_HTTP_Cookie[]) Array of response cookies.
- 'http_response' (WP_HTTP_Requests_Response|null) Raw HTTP response object.

So to check what the HTTP response code is:

```php
echo $response['code'];
```

Here, you want the `body`, and to make it easier, `wp_remote_retrieve_body`

```
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $result )
// or..
$body = $result['body'];
```

Then we can `json_decode`. Note that I did not nest the function calls, that would make it really difficult to debug, and impossible to perform error checks.

Don't forget that `json_decode` needs error handling too! Don't just assume it worked.

Comment: I removed the escaping function and added the error checking code like you mentioned but still it is showing the "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error but if I add "(array)" in front of "return (array)json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );" (like that), then the error does not show but the function still does not work.

Comment: ***you should never nest them like that***, it makes it impossible to debug and you can't do error checking. I cannot diagnose the problem if you nest the functions. Assign the result of `wp_remote_retrieve_body` to a variable and error check it. We need to know where it fails, and we can't do that without error checks. If it still does not work, I need to know which check gets triggered. Even when it starts working, include the error checks, always have error checks. I cannot emphasise enough how important error checks are.

Comment: Just to be clear what I mean by nesting: `foo( bar( 'stuff' ) )`, this is very bad practice and very difficult to debug. Instead do this: `$a = bar( 'stuff' ); foo( $a );`